# Get last not-0 cell from different sheets

Tags: google-sheets

What i'm trying to achieve here is this scenario:

assuming i have 12 sheets (1 for each month) with 1 cell (for instance A1) that is initialized 0 at the beginning and every month i update it .
Once it differs from 0 the first time it can change (but never BECOME 0 again).

```
January 10
February 14
March 36
april 84
may 190
June 0
july 0
...
```

What i'm trying to achieve here is getting, in another sheet, the last value it has before being 0 (so in this example 190 is the outcome)

what I did so far is getting the cell value like this

```
January!A1
```

But i'm not sure how to put the if condition and concatenate it to get the last one.

EDIT:

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NH48EhK6oL817cD2Vb1ZUEadvyv3xgMAcdEfhAojXuk/edit?usp=sharing) a sheet example

[image: HERE]

Comment: @BigBen is actually google-sheets, SE suggested me to add the excel tag.
modified

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with demo data and expected output(manually entered) so that it gives a clear picture for us to work it out... @Anon

Comment: @rockinfreakshow added the sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `month` tabs list is arranged in ***Column_F*** & then you can use:

```
=let(Σ,reduce(,tocol(F:F,1),lambda(a,c,{a;indirect("'"&c&"'!A1")})),
       lookup(9^9,filter(Σ,Σ<>0)))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to adapt the script in my sheet (A1 ->F8) but it does not work.
If i paste it as it is it splits in 2 cells. if "trim" it it gets me this error

Did not find value '387420489' in LOOKUP evaluation.

Comment: You could recreate the error scenario here in the sample sheet & we can troubleshoot

Comment: i can paste you a screen of my original sheet , month list is in italian but recreates perfectly the sheets names

Comment: sorry that doesn't help!

Comment: found the problem, at the beginning my cell are all 0, the script does not work if every cell has 0 in it.
How can it be modified so it can have a "0" default value?

Comment: this part of formula `lookup(9^9,filter(Σ,Σ<>0))` can be changed to `ifna(lookup(9^9,filter(Σ,Σ<>0)),0)`